# backslashes visible in output

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I make the backslash so that it becomes visible in the output of the code?
I am trying to make a board for a game I am programming. however, the board contains backslashes '\'

```py
print('''
  _____________________
 /                     \
/_______________________\
|     |     |     |     |

''')
```

but what I get is:

```py
>>>
      _____________________
     /                     /_______________________|     |     |     |     |
>>>
```

Comment: I'm not sure about Python, but in C and C++, the backslash is a special character.  \n means newline, \t is tab, etc.  To get a backslash, you have to double it up like \\.

Comment: You're almost there. You need to escape the backslashes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to escaping you can use raw print. Notice the `r` before the `'''`:

```
print(r'''
  _____________________
 /                     \
/_______________________\
|     |     |     |     |

''')
```

Comment: Nice I forgot about `r`. Like that solution :). +1

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape your backslash by preceding it with, yes, another backslash:

```
print('''
  _____________________
 /                     \\
/_______________________\\
|     |     |     |     |

''')
```

Or instead, you can use `r` (or `R`) to specify a string literal called "raw strings"-- omitting the need of escaping the backslashes

```
print(R'''
  _____________________
 /                     \
/_______________________\
|     |     |     |     |

''')
```

Comment: Using capital `R`, one preserves cross-language consistency with C (through the GNU compiler)/C++ (language). Not a requirement per sé, but it may guide your choice in _some_ situations.

Comment: It is important in a lot of situation. Thanks for that info!